# How can I restart Elasticsearch K8S deployment

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I deploy a Elasticsearch cluster to EKS, below is the spec

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elk
spec:
  version: 7.15.2
  serviceAccountName: docker-sa
  http:
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        disabled: true
  nodeSets:
  - name: node
    count: 3
    config:
  ...
```

I can see it has been deployed correctly and all pods are running.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elk-es-node-0                1/1     Running   0          19h
elk-es-node-1                1/1     Running   0          19h
elk-es-node-2                1/1     Running   0          11h
```

But I can't restart the deployment `Elasticsearch`,

```
$ kubectl rollout restart Elasticsearch elk-es-node
Error from server (NotFound): elasticsearches.elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co "elk-es-node" not found
```

The Elasticsearch is using `statefulset` so I tried to restart `statefulset`,

```
$ kubectl rollout restart statefulset elk-es-node
statefulset.apps/elk-es-node restarted
```

the above command says `restarted`, but the actual pods are not restarting.

what is the right way to restart a custom kind in K8S?

Comment: It's going to be `kubectl rollout restart <statefulset name>`, assuming it creates a statefulset. Check `kubectl get statefulset`

Comment: yes, you are right, it is statefulset. But how can I know whether it is statefulset or deployment?

Comment: "Controlled By" in `describe pod` output. Deployment will point to a replicaset.

Comment: I tried to restart the statefulset and the command response say success but the pods are not restart. I added details on the question.

Comment: Check the upgrade strategy for the statefulset. rollout restart may not work if its set to `onDelete`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#update-strategies

Answer (score 1):

Use - ***`kubectl get all`***

To identify if the resource created is a deployment or a statefulset -
use `-n <namespace">` along with the above command, if you are working in a specific namespace.

Assuming, you are using a statefulset, the issue below command to understand the properties in which it is configured.

`kubectl get statefulset <statefulset-name"> -o yaml  > statefulsetContent.yaml`

- this will create a yaml file names statefulsetContent.yaml in same directory.
- you can use it to explore different options configured in the statefulset.

Check for `.spec.updateStrategy` in the yaml file. Based on this we can identify its update strategy.

Below is from the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#update-strategies)

There are two possible values:

> - **OnDelete**
>
> When a StatefulSet's `.spec.updateStrategy.type` is set to `OnDelete`, the StatefulSet controller will not automatically update the Pods in a StatefulSet. Users must manually delete Pods to cause the controller to create new Pods that reflect modifications made to a StatefulSet's `.spec.template`.
>
> - **RollingUpdate**
>
> The `RollingUpdate` update strategy implements automated, rolling update for the Pods in a StatefulSet. This is the default update strategy.

As a work around, you can try to scale down/up the `statefulset`.

`kubectl scale sts <statefulset-name"> --replicas=<count">`

Answer (score 0):

With ECK as the operator, you do not need to use rollout restart. Apply your updated Elasticsearch spec and the operator will perform rolling update for you. If for any reason you need to restart a pod, you use `kubectl delete pod <es pod> -n <your es namespace>` to remove the pod and the operator will spin up new one for you.

Comment: I tried to update the spec but it doesn't always restart. If I use `delete`, will it do a rolling update restart?

Comment: If it does not restart means the change you made does not require one. Delete is **not** rolling restart. Typically, you only delete an ES pod when it is causing problem in the ES cluster.